# I "run out of application memory" when trying to render a scene

Tags: error, osx, memory-management

I spent a long time designing a scene which involves 5 particle systems (no more than 1000 particles in each), and now I would like to render it.

Unfortunately, I invariably get this error message when I start trying to render it:

[image: [screenshot]]

This is a problem brought up [in this discussion](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/178281/how-to-investigate-high-kernel-task-memory-usage) but this page doesn't give solutions I can apply.

There is no doubt for me that Blender is the culprit, since I tried to render the same scene on two different computers and got the same error messages on each one, even when Blender was the only program running.

**Computer 1**

[image]

[image]

**Computer 2**

[image]

[image]

Is there anything I can do to make sure I can render this scene without crashing the computer? I tried quitting all the other apps besides Blender, and rendering as a PNG instead as EXR, but it doesn't make a difference.

(I would share the file but it is around 50 megs, is there a way to do so?)

Comment: Particles use up a lot of memory. What I normally do, is to create different scenes (e.g.: 5 particle systems = 5 scenes)  - if that's possible of course -, then render one scene at the time making sure to leave the background transparent (alpha). When all the scenes have been rendered (use png or similar and not a video format), open the video editor and put each rendered series on top of each other in a different channel. Only one series can have the background activated but the shadows can be a little tricky. I hope this helps!

Comment: I wouldn't expect to have issues with 16GB of ram. Try clearing all bakes in the particle cache and then make a compressed copy of the blend to see how small you can get it. If you don't have hosting to upload to have a [look here](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/q/344/935).